# ASP.NET MVC 4 + Google OAuth for example.com and www.example.com is treated as two different

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I have setup OAuth using a Microsoft/Google/Facebook account on a ASP.NET MVC 4 site. The site can be accessed both using www.example.com and example.com. When using a Microsoft or a Facebook login a user that have created an account on www.example.com can login on example.com. However when using the Google account a user that have created an login on www.example.com cannot use that login on example.com.

My question: Is it possible to setup the Google OAuth so that it has the same behavior as the Microsoft and Facebook login (www.example.com and example.com are treated as one site)?

Comment: This behavior is by design for OpenID; AFAIK, you can't change it.  This should not happen for OAuth 2.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks - I will have a look at OAuth 2